# Have 2 iCloud accounts in my mac and don't know how

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, icloud, accounts

I have 2 iCloud accounts and don't know how, I tried to delete the deactivated one (the bottom one in the image) but when i deleted it, my mac deleted the other (which was active).

[image: accounts bug/error]

When the 2 accounts was deleted I created again my iCloud account but still have 2 iCloud accounts.

How I resolve this issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you signed into another Apple ID anywhere else, such as Messages?

Comment: @tubedogg    no i am not signed with another apple id, i have only 1, but i have in my ipad.

Comment: Have you signed in with another Apple ID before? Possibility is that your Macbook remembered the record.

Answer (score 1):

I have two iCloud accounts on my Mac (and in fact, most of my selected iOS devices) because of the way Apple IDs work.

One of them iCloud accounts is used for iCloud syncing, etc and the email address attached to it is not of an Apple-owned domain (e.g. @icloud.com, @me.com).

The second iCloud account is most likely your iCloud email account.

Comment: but the second is deactivated and says: This is not your primary iCloud account. but it is, only changes the email, the first one is (at)me.com the second (at)gmail.com but these emails are in the same account